# How do I get a running sum command to end?

Tags: python, sum

I’m trying to have a running sum command that ends once the total is greater than 100, then shows the final sum of the inputs and the amount of numbers entered, but it doesn’t stop when the sum is greater than 100.
Here’s my code:

```
c = 0
total = 0

while (total <= 100):
    c = c + 1
    b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    total = a + b

print ("Sum: " + str(total))
print("Numbers Entered: " + str(c))
```

Comment: What's `a`? Didn't it give a `NameError`?

Answer (score 0):

```
# use functions with params!
def get_total(max_total: int = 100) -> tuple:
    total = 0
    c = 0

    while (total <= max_total):
        c += 1
        b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        # same as 'total = total + b'
        total += b
    # You can pack few variables to a tuple
    return total, c

# function result unpacking
# I called function get_total() with arg == 100 for param 'max_total'
total, c = get_total(100)
print ("Sum: " + str(total))
print("Numbers Entered: " + str(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `a` you can use `total` variable

```
c = 0
total = 0

while (total <= 100):
    b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    total += b
    c = c+1
print ("Sum: " + str(total))
print("Numbers Entered: " + str(c))
```